# Stored Procedure error in POSTGRESQL PGADMIN4

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.4, sql-function

I am getting the below error when I try to create either a stored procedure or a stored function in PGADMIN4. How can I fix it:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "procedure"
>
> LINE 1: create or replace procedure transfer(

The code to create the tables:

```
drop table if exists accounts;
create table accounts (
    id int generated by default as identity,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    balance dec(15,2) not null,
    primary key(id)
);
insert into accounts(name,balance) values('Bob',10000);
insert into accounts(name,balance) values('Alice',10000);
```

Error is received after I add the below stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure transfer(
   sender int,
   receiver int, 
   amount dec
)
language plpgsql    
as $$
begin
    -- subtracting the amount from the sender's account 
    update accounts 
    set balance = balance - amount 
    where id = sender;

    -- adding the amount to the receiver's account
    update accounts 
    set balance = balance + amount 
    where id = receiver;

    commit;
end;$$
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't add the code correctly above which was giving the problem:
create or replace procedure transfer(
   sender int,
   receiver int, 
   amount dec
)
language plpgsql    
as $$
begin
    -- subtracting the amount from the sender's account 
    update accounts 
    set balance = balance - amount 
    where id = sender;

    -- adding the amount to the receiver's account
    update accounts 
    set balance = balance + amount 
    where id = receiver;

    commit;
end;$$

Comment: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  and it did not supported procedures. You should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Procedures are available in Postgres starting version 11 only, while you tagged your question with version 9.4.

In earlier versions, you can use a void function instead. Basically, replace:

```
create or replace procedure transfer(sender int, receiver int, amount dec)
language plpgsql    
as $$
begin
    ...
end; $$
```

With:

```
create or replace function transfer(sender int, receiver int, amount dec)
returns void
language plpgsql    
as $$
begin
    ...
end; $$
```